# Error depending on choice of build configuration (Debug vs Release)

Tags: c#, preprocessor

In one of my projects I have two configuration files: One contains config-data for the dev-environment, one contains config-data for the release-environment.

I want the configuration file to be picked based on build configuration, so I came up with the following snippet:

```
#if DEBUG
    private static FileInfo ConfigFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine("xml", "dev-config.xml"));
    private static FileInfo RepoFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine("xml", "dev-repositories.xml"));
#else
    private static FileInfo ConfigFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine("xml", "release-config.xml"));
    private static FileInfo RepoFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine("xml", "release-repositories.xml"));
#endif
```

When selecting the `Debug`-build-config, the code compiles fine and produces a useful executable

[image: Visual Studio if Debug is selected]

If however I choose `Release`-build-config, suddenly the compiler tells me that a certain type cannot be resolved

[image: Visual Studio if Release is selected]

So I guess this is due to a poor Preprocessor declaration, but I cannot find the mistake here

Comment: At a guess, I would say that there is something about the `RiceFryerConfig` class and it not liking the Release build. The other stuff is Software Development basics, I do it all the time, in several places

Comment: @JayV I commented out the `RiceFryerConfig`-Line and it does not throw an exception anymore. The config class though is as simple as it could be. A constructor and two properties

Comment: It is getting even weirder `========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped =========` when compiling it. Just Visual Studio is making troubles. Restarting Visual Studio does not help